# QWebEnginePage: toHtml returns an empty string

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I need to retrieve some html from a `QWebEnginePage`. I found in the documentation the method [toHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#toHtml) but it always returns an empty string. I tried [toPlainText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#toPlainText)
 and it works, but this is not what I need.

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
   _wp = new QWebEnginePage();
   _wp->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::AutoLoadImages, false);
   _wp->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
   connect(_wp, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(wpLoadFinished(bool)));
}
void MyClass::start()
{
   _wp->load(QUrl("http://google.com/"));
}
void MyClass::wpLoadFinished(bool s)
{
   _wp->toHtml(
       [] (const QString &result) {
          qDebug()<<"html:";
          qDebug()<<result;
    }); // return empty string
    /*_wp->toPlainText(
       [] (const QString &result) {
          qDebug()<<"txt:";
          qDebug()<<result;
    });*/ //works perfectly
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I put the load() function right after the connect statement, removed the start() function and it worked perfect with toHtml().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am getting my head around  QWebEngine. It is very cool. I have got the following to work.

The lambada capture needs to be all that is "=", or "this" in the case of signal being emitted.  You would also need "mutable" to modify the captured copies.  `toHtml()` is however asynchronous so even if you capture the html it is unlikely it would be available directly after the call to `toHtml()` in `SomeFunction`. You can overcome this by using a signal and slot.

```
protected slots:
    void handleHtml(QString sHtml);

signals:
    void html(QString sHtml);



 void MainWindow::SomeFunction()
 {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(html(QString)), this, SLOT(handleHtml(QString)));
    view->page()->toHtml([this](const QString& result) mutable {emit html(result);});
 }

void MainWindow::handleHtml(QString sHtml)
{
      qDebug()<<"myhtml"<< sHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is more a connection problem. Your code works fine on my appli :

```
    connect(page, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this,   SLOT(pageLoadFinished(bool)));
```

...

```
    page->load(QUrl("http://google.com/"));
```

...loading time...

```
 void MaClasse :: pageLoadFinished(bool s){
   page->toHtml([this](const QString &result){         
   qDebug()<<"html:";
   qDebug()<<result;
   item->setHtml(result);});
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13320562)

Comment: I don't need your courtesy to tell that this code works fine on my application. Accordingly to the fact that it do works, i think that it's a part of the answer, don't you?