# Is there a library for executing html?

Tags: python, html

Im making a simple web browser and i obviously need a way to "render" the html code it recieves. What libraries have the ability to do stuff with html files?

I tried googling the solution but there are only ways to execute python in html, while i need the other way around.

"""
code doesn't exist since this "problem" is step 1
"""

Comment: HTML isn't executable. JavaScript is

Comment: HTML is not executable code. it is a markup language that describes how things appear on a page.

Comment: I think he meant he wants to render/display HTML in his mission `simple web browser`. By the way why you want to do that when there are plenty of browsers in the market freely available? Is it an exercise?

Comment: @fiveelements This sort of thing could be useful if you wanted to, for instance, generate a preview of a page in Python and generate or modify an image of it using Pillow.

Comment: Or if you want to create a standalone desktop app with Python but you want to be able to use html instead of Tkinter or something for the interface.  Electronjs would be good for this, but it uses javascript instead of Python.

Comment: @kloddant I think you have mistakenly addressed me. I did not ask the question, just clarified the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [PyQt5 library](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/). It has a `QWebEngineView` that can be used to render HTML.

[Here's a relevant question that might get you started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754138/how-to-render-html-with-pyqt5s-qwebengineview)