# Render html tags attrs on QtWebEngine page in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I am working on a Qt project that requires some HTML tags attrs to be rendered over the main page. for example, id or class name. But I am not sure exactly how to proceed with this. Does anyone have previous experience rendering custom text over PyQtWebEngine?

I attached an example of what I am describing:

[image]

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754138/how-to-render-html-with-pyqt5s-qwebengineview

Comment: @jspcal, yeah, I did check that out first. but that isn't what I am looking for.  I am trying to render HTML tag attributes on top of the actual HTML page as shown in the image attached to the post. So it is like creating a composite.

Comment: @AbdulroqeebAriwoola That may be tricky, even impossible. First of all, the web view doesn't draw anything on its own, it delegates drawing to a *private* QOpenGlWidget subclass. Even if you filter for `Paint` events in the child (to ensure that the content is updated), it's still possible that you'll see nothing due to the way the OS draws accelerated content. In any case, just try: override the `paintEvent()` of the view, create a painter on the viewport (`painter = QPainter(self.viewport())` and try to draw something. Still, even if it works, there's no guarantee that it will on any system.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for the note. doesn't seem to work though.

```class Browser(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self) 
        qp.begin(self) 
 
        qp.setPen(QColor(200,0,0)) 
        qp.drawText(20, 20, "Text") 
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, "Text") 
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.darkGreen, 4)) 
        qp.drawEllipse(QPoint(50,60),30,30) 
 
        qp.end()```

Comment: Then the only possibility I can think of is to try to add a child widget on the QWebEngineView, make it transparent and add custom painting. Note that: 1. the transparency might require much care, because, as said, the drawing is done on an OpenGL widget, and that could create issues on some platforms, so you need to be careful about that in order to ensure that the content will always be visible; 2. for obvious reasons, all "overlayed" content must be realigned whenever the page is updated/scrolled, as there's no direct way to achieve that using standard Qt methods. It still may not work.

Comment: @musicamante, looking closely at your first solution, I see that it indeed worked. however, the webpage quickly rendered over it. Do you know if there is a way to set the z-index on the painter to make it paint over the page? Otherwise, I will try again your new proposal.

Comment: @AbdulroqeebAriwoola No, as said, rendering of the web view is external from the standard painting, as it happens in a different widget that uses a different rendering/stacking/buffer mechanism; the painter only draws at the widget level and follows the parent/child stacking order, if there is a *child* widget, it will **always** paint *over* the parent. So, the only possibility left is to try with a different child widget.